# how can you anchor the hamburger icon to mobile navigation bar for various screen sizes in CSS>

Tags: html, css

The navigation works correctly on large screens and mobile devices. The issue i have is when you add a title to the website, this is currently commented out in the html supplied "Div header". The larger screens work okay.
On the smaller device screens the Hamburger toggle item does not stay within the Mobile Nav bar.

I have tried using all the position values but to no avail.
Is their a way of achieving this within my CSS.
look forward to any help given

```js
(function($) { 

   /* create dropdown menu large screen */

  $(function() { 
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
    /* close submenu on click large screen */
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    
    /* create mobile dropdown menu and close sub menu on click*/
    
     $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();

    }); 
     
        /* change Hamburger to cross when Hamburger clicked  */
        
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
      });   
    
    /* close down menu when submenu item clicked  */
    
     $('a.ditem').click(function() {
        $('#nav-toggle').toggleClass('active'); 
          $('nav ul').hide();
      });

    
      /*  hide main mobile menu  change back to Hamburger sign */
      
     $('a.mmenu').click(function() {
        $('#nav-toggle').toggleClass('active');
        /* edited here*/
      $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });  
    
     
    
    
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
  <style type="text/css">
    
    /* Base CSS for lion respomsive site */
    
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
  {
     font-family: Arial,'Righteous', cursive;  
    } 

h1 { 

font-family: Arial; 

/* font-size: 25px; */

font-size: 2.0em;

font-weight: bold; 

color: #000080;

text-align: center; 

}   
    .nav-bar {
      height: 70px;
       background: #262626;
    }
 
     .brand {
 
      display: none;
    }
.brand a img {
    max-height: 70px;
}
.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 
 /* position navbar items */
nav {
  
  float: center ;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: #2ab1ce;
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}
nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
 
.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626  /*  background color of hamburger  */
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}
 
@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
 
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 25%;
     
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
 
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
  .brand {
       position: absolute;
        padding-left: 20px;
       float: left;
       line-height: 70px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.4em; 
      display: block;
  }
    .brand a img {
        max-height: 60px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        display: block;
        
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;   /* color of hamburger icon  */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);  
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
   transform: rotate(-45deg); 
  
 
}
```

```html
<html>
 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Responsive Dropdown nav-bar Bar</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/idea1.css"> 
</head>
 
<body>
 <!-- <div id="header">
         <br>

             <h1>   

              My Website<br></h1>

                     

          </div>   <!-- end middle -->
 
  <section class="nav-bar">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="">MENU</a>
    </div>
   
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a class="mmenu" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class=dmenu" href="#">Web Development</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a class="ditem" href="#">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="ditem"href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="ditem" href="#">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="mmenu" href="#!">SEO</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="mmenu"href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
 
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="media/idea1.js"></script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on  `background: #262626 /* background color of hamburger */` that you forgot to put `;` in here:

```
  .nav-mobile {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     background: #262626; /*  background color of hamburger  */
     height: 70px;
     width: 70px;
  }
```

And because of that, the navigation background is white and not visible to the eye.
You also need to adjust the `top:0` as the header will have its own height. Or put a `position: relative` on the parent element of the mobile-button

```
nav {
    position: relative; /* Add this position so Absolute value on the mobile button will be relative to is parent element*/
}
```

```js
(function($) {

  /* create dropdown menu large screen */

  $(function() {
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    /* close submenu on click large screen */
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });

    /* create mobile dropdown menu and close sub menu on click*/

    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();

    });

    /* change Hamburger to cross when Hamburger clicked  */

    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });

    /* close down menu when submenu item clicked  */

    $('a.ditem').click(function() {
      $('#nav-toggle').toggleClass('active');
      $('nav ul').hide();
    });


    /*  hide main mobile menu  change back to Hamburger sign */

    $('a.mmenu').click(function() {
      $('#nav-toggle').toggleClass('active');
      /* edited here*/
      $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });




  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* Base CSS for lion respomsive site */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

{
  font-family: Arial, 'Righteous', cursive;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  /* font-size: 25px; */
  font-size: 2.0em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000080;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-bar {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}

.brand {
  display: none;
}

.brand a img {
  max-height: 70px;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* position navbar items */

nav {
  float: center;
  position: relative;
  /* Add this position so Absolute value on the mobile button will be relative to is parent element*/
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: #2ab1ce;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  /*  background color of hamburger  */
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 25%;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
  .brand {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: block;
  }
  .brand a img {
    max-height: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* color of hamburger icon  */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Responsive Dropdown nav-bar Bar</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/idea1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <br>
    <h1>My Website<br></h1>
  </div>
  <section class="nav-bar">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <div class="brand">
        <a href="">MENU</a>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li>
            <a class="mmenu" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class=dmenu " href="# ">Web Development</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown ">
            <li>
              <a class="ditem " href="# ">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="ditem "href="# ">CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="ditem " href="# ">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="mmenu " href="#! ">SEO</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="mmenu "href="# ">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
 
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script  src="media/idea1.js "></script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help have been going around in a circle for several days.

Comment: @GrahamaRoberts No worries. You can also check the Developer tools in Chrome when you are testing by inspecting the element so you can check the CSS why of that element.